# Setting audio quality in moive.py python (audio size was 1.50 GB and when I convert it to video, it becomes only 500 MB)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I am trying to set audio quality in the video while exporting it. I have tried many ways to do it but I am not getting it.
Please tell me how to set an external audio quality while combining it to the video in movie.py python.

In detail:

I am trying to add a 1.50 GB external audio file to the video and when its export, the total size of the video was only 500 MB. Can you imagine how much my audio file was compressed, so I want my audio should be of high quality.
I am doing it on windows 10, movie.py python

Code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import moviepy.editor as mpy
import os

directory_root = os.path.join("R:/", "Rajat", "voices", "same images")
files = os.listdir(directory_root)
files = [os.path.join(directory_root, f) for f in files]

clip = mpy.ImageSequenceClip(files, fps=1)
audioClip = AudioFileClip('play.mp3')


newclip = clip.set_audio(audioClip)
newclip.write_videofile("my_video6.mp4")
```

Tell me how I can increase my audio quality?